# Fetch request with FormData Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I am trying to send html table inside append of FormData object using fetch request.
Code is Correct for these

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('sponsor', "My sponsor");
formData.append('rider', "xRider");
```

But When trying to send an html in it Fetch request fails

```
formData.append('delegation', "<b>Bold Text</b>");
```

My complete request

```
fetch(request_url, {
            method: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) return response.json();
        })
        .then(response => {
            let response_status = response['status'] == 'success' ? 'success' : 'failed';
            // In case of OK, this sendResponse will be called
            Console.log("Working correctly")
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // In case of error, this sendResponse will be called
            call_back_function({
                status: "failed",
                data: error
            });
            console.log('%c View Visa Details Catch Error: ', 'background: #000; color: #bada55', error)
        });
```

Comment: What the error you get? What's your server code?

Answer (score 0):

So this is an example from an actual project I am making. I don't see all of your code, so I can't see you request, or headers. But try something like this! or post all of your code so we can properly see everything.

```
export const NewPost = async(endpoint, body) =>
{
    const headers  = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const options = {
        method:'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers:headers,
    };

    const request = new Request(endpoint, options);

    const response = await fetch(request).then((response) => 
    {
        if(response.ok)
            return response.json();
            
        throw new Error(`Response not received. Status: ${response.status}`);
    })
    .then((json) => 
    { 
        console.log(`POST Request successful.`); 
        return json; 
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

    return response;
};
```